# Visual Studio for Mac - Support for UWP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, uwp, visual-studio-mac

According to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Core it shows that .net core supports four-cross platform scenarios:

- ASP.NET Core web apps
- Command-line apps
- Libraries
- Universal Windows Platform apps

What I want to know is, does the Visual Studio for Mac IDE support creating desktop 'universal apps' that can be executed on a mac system?

OR

Is this only supported in the Visual Studio IDE for the Windows platform?

Comment: .NET Core is cross-platform but UWP is Win10 only

Comment: UWP is W10 only. You may use Xamarin.Forms if you want to build cross platform apps with UI. .NET Core supports only console and web applications at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can't use UWP on the `MAC` as UWP supports Windows 10 eco system (Win10,IOT,XBox)  but you can use `.Net Core to build cross platform console app and asp.net core to make web services and webapps`.

Comment: Ah so web apps are supported however desktops apps are not supported! I guess Microsoft are 50% there.

Does anyone know if there are any plans for Microsoft to support UWP desktop apps on the mac osx?

Comment: yes basically UI stuff is mostly hard to do with crossplatform

Comment: @TheOne you can create cross platform apps. You have a shared project where you can share most components between the projects for MacOS and Windows. Checkout the My driving sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MyDriving

Comment: is it possible to build on VS Mac and deploy remotely?

Comment: yes most of build tools are cross platform and will work

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no opportunity to use UWP on the MAC. The same is for Linux.
UWP is only for the windows ecosystem.